# Why My Applicaion cannot display unicode character correctly?

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

I decided to turn my win32 c++ application into Unicode version but when I use that i got unreadable letters for Arabic, Chinese and Japanese...

First:

If I don't use Unicode I got Arabic ok in edit boxes Window titles:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", "ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 300, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)100, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

SetWindowText(hWnd, "صباح الخير");
```

The output seems ok and works fine! (without unicode).

- With Unicode:

I added before inclusion headers:

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h
```

Now in Window Procedure:

```
case WM_CREATE:{
    HWND hEdit = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, L"Edit", L"ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 300, 200, hWnd, (HMENU)100, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

    // Even I send message to change text but I get unreadable characters!
}
break;
case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:{
    SendDlgItemMessageW(hWnd, 100, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)L"السلام عليكم"); // Get unreadable characters also
}
break;
```

ِAs you can see with Unicode the controls cannot display Arabic characters correctly.

- The thing that matters is: After the control is created I delete the content manually with `backspace` Now If I enter an Arabic text manually It succeeds to display it correctly?!!! But why Wen using Functions? Like `SetWindowTextW()`??

Please Help. Thank you.

Comment: regardless of you program: make sure the console has the codepage set to unicode and to a font that has those characters.

Comment: I highly recommend http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @Jodocus the Win32 API does not support UTF-8, only ANSI and UTF-16

Comment: @ Remy: Check on Q-15: Won’t the conversions between UTF-8 and UTF-16 when passing strings to Windows slow down my application?

Comment: @WonFeiHong: try assigning a Unicode-enabled font to the Edit control using [`WM_SETFONT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642.aspx).

Comment: @Jodocus: I'm aware of that. That doesn't solve the problem. Won is ALREADY using UTF-16 when interacting with the API.  Using UTF-8 strings in memory and converting them to UTF-16 doesn't fix anything

Comment: @RemyLebeau: How can I? could you give a simple example please?

Comment: @ Remy: I never claimed to solve his problem (that's why I am commenting). I just wanted to give him a hint to something that can prevent many more problems in future.

Comment: @WonFeiHong: did you read the documentation I linked to? Do you know how to load an `HFONT`? Hint: look at [`CreateFont()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499.aspx) or [`CreateFontIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183500.aspx)

Comment: @Jodocus: your suggestion to use UTF-8 doesn't help ANYTHING in this situation. The ONLY thing it really solves on Windows is memory usage, except for Asian languages where UTF-16 is actually more compact than UTF-16. In general, UTF-16 strings are easier to work with in general, that is why MOST platforms use UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 (don't get me started on *Nix, that is in the minority here). UTF-8 has its uses, particular for communications, but not so much for GUIs and APIs.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I think I can use `CreateFont()` and `SendMessage` with `WM_SETFONT` But what family of the font will use?

Comment: @ Remy: "Use comments to [...] suggest improvements." I will not repeat myself.

Comment: @WonFeiHong: [Unicode fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I read them thanx.

Comment: You didn't what compiler you are using?

Comment: @Jodocus: The suggestion to use UTF-8 does not improve anything. It worsens the situation. UTF-8 is fine as a serialization protocol. When programming against the Windows API, it causes more trouble than it solves (incidentally, it doesn't solve *anything*). Being dogmatic without fully understanding the constraints is a very dangerous combination.

Comment: @ llinspectable: Please do not impute dogmatism to me, I am absolutely not. The advantages of an "always use UTF-8" attitude and to use conversions to UTF-16 when calling the WinAPI are described quite rationally at this link. In fact, even the right answer to this question was to configure the compiler to treat input as UTF-8, which you would do anyways if you follow the "UTF-8 everywhere" guideline as you accept no indetermination of what character set is used, but you can rely on that it is always UTF-8.

Comment: @Jodocus: Yes, the document *tries* hard to make a point, but fails in the end. In case you missed the essence of the currently highest-voted answer: It instructs the compiler to generate a UTF-16 encoded string literal, but stores the source file as UTF-8. This is in the vast majority of cases the right thing to do on Windows. And it certainly does not follow the "UTF-8 everywhere" mantra.

Comment: @IInspectable I don’t think this is the place to fight that particular holy war. What I’ve heard people say, though, is that external data files, such as source code, should always be saved in UTF-8 (and frequently that there should never be a BOM), not that no programmer should ever use UTF-16 data with something like the Windows API or QT at all.

Comment: @Davislor: The paper/proposal posted by Jodocus does indeed recommend to never use UTF-16, even when targeting Windows. According to it, string data should always be stored as UTF-8, and only convert to/from UTF-16 at the API boundary. This is not a holy war. It's a conscious decision, and using UTF-8 in a Windows application is more often than not the wrong choice. Being dogmatic about it (like the paper) is *always* an error.

Comment: @IInspectable I’m not going to argue which representation it would be better to use, but I note that the linked page actually says not to use UTF-16 literals “in any place other than parameters to APIs accepting UTF-16.” Which is the case here. So even they are not so dogmatic as to object to this code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure to save the source file as UTF-16 or UTF-8 with BOM.  Many Windows applications assume the ANSI encoding (default localized Windows code page) otherwise.  You can also check compiler switches to force using UTF-8 for source files.  For example, MS Visual Studio 2015's compiler has a `/utf-8` switch so saving with BOM is not required.

Here's a simple example saved in UTF-8, and then UTF-8 w/ BOM and compiled with the Microsoft Visual Studio compiler.  Note that there is no need to define UNICODE if you hard-code the W versions of the APIs and use L"" for wide strings:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL,L"ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ",L"中文",MB_OK);
}
```

Result (UTF-8).  The compiler assumed ANSI encoding (Windows-1252) and decoded the wide string incorrectly.

[image: Corrupted image]

Result (UTF-8 w/ BOM).  The compiler detects the BOM and uses UTF-8 to decode the source code, resulting in the correct data generated for the wide strings.

[image: Correct image]

A little Python code demonstrating the decode error:

```
>>> s='中文,ا ب ت ث ج ح خ د ذ'
>>> print(s.encode('utf8').decode('Windows-1252'))
ä¸­æ–‡,Ø§ Ø¨ Øª Ø« Ø¬ Ø­ Ø® Ø¯ Ø°
```

Comment: "Result (UTF-8 w/ BOM)" doesn't work with plain WinAPI. I think you are using a python script which is making UTF-16 conversion somewhere.

Comment: He's doing it right, he ensured that the *source code file* was encoded correctly.  The BOM is no longer relevant at runtime, that just produces dabomb.

Comment: Yes, and the BOM isn't even required if the compiler supports a switch to assume UTF-8.  You just have to make sure the compiler chooses the right encoding when decoding the wide strings in the source code.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I used exactly what I posted.  C code saved as UTF-8 and UTF-8 w/ BOM compiled with a Microsoft compiler.  It sounds like you are trying to use the non-Unicode WinAPI.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood your post. I thought *"Result (UTF-8 w/ BOM)"* was meant to imply that UTF-8 is being used in API. I can't read so good.

Comment: I’d always strongly recommend UTF-8 over UTF-16 for source code and other text files. And writing code that has to compile on Visual Studio is one of the rare times I would recommend a BOM.

Comment: @Davislor CSV files read by Excel is another time.  Many Windows apps assume ANSI without a BOM.

Comment: It works fine on `MSVC14` but on old Compilers like MSVC++ 6.0 it doesn't work.

Comment: @WonFeiHong For that old compiler you might have to use UTF16. Did you try it?

Comment: @WonFeiHong Check out this documentation on MSDN, and select the old compiler from the “Other Versions” drop-down. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwy0e8f2.aspx)  Many older MS products only autodetect UTF-8 with a BOM and some do not even have a setting to override that behavior.

Comment: @WonFeiHong UTF-8 with BOM is the only encoding that clang, gcc and MSVC 15 will all recognize without any special command-line magic. I know there are versions of clang that only support UTF-8. My advice is to upgrade any part of your toolchain that breaks on UTF-8. However, if you need to fall back to ASCII, there are the Unicode escapes, such as `'\u0086'`. (But do compilers more than a decade old understand those, either?)

Comment: @WonFeiHong Use an editor that can save files in different encodings to save your source in another encoding. Notepad++ is what I used.

Comment: @WonFeiHong MSVC6.0 compiler won't accept UTF-16 files. Last time I tried, the best you can do for such old compiler is to use UTF-8 string literal and convert to UTF-16 on runtime with `MultiByteToWideChar`.

Comment: @raymai97: Thank you.

Comment: @raymai97: It will be great help if you post how to do that please. Thank you.

Comment: @WonFeiHong I suggest that you post a new question specific for VC6 then (mention VC6 in question title). That would help other people with similar question in future.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out!

1- Before compiling and building my program: I went to control panel and changed everything to Arabic (Language) and restarted the computer.

2- I Set vc++ 6.0 to use Unicode through defining the macros `UNICODE`, `_UNICODE` and disabling Multi-Byte-Character-String `_MBCS`.

And as @Remy Lebeau suggested I chose `Simplified Arabic` font (Unicode fnot) in my compiler.

Finally I added the output `entrypoint` to the linker output `wWinMainCRTStartup`.

Now I compiled and build the program setting some button to change the text of the edit control to Arabic string. The result I got what I wanted! Thank you All guys!

- The thing that in VC++ 14 No problem there I can define `unicode easily.